# Constructing a family of sets

Tags: set-theory

I am completely stuck at the following question.

Suppose $X$ is an infinite set. Show that there is a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following:

(a) If $A \subseteq X$ is finite, then $A \in \mathcal{F}$ iff $|A|$ is even.

(b) If $A, B$ are disjoint subsets of $X$, then $A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$ iff either $A, B $ are both in $\mathcal{F}$ or $A, B$ are both not in $\mathcal{F}$.

What I tried: I started by adding all even size sets to $\mathcal{F}$ and then tried to use Zorn's lemma but could not come up with a partial order to make it work.

Could someone give me any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Consider the partial order defined by inclusion on the set of all families $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$.

Comment: @xyzzyz Your hint is too cryptic for me. The "set of all families $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $X$" has a unique maximal element, namely $\mathcal P(X)$, which indeed satisfies (b), but does not satisfy (a) unless $X=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $[X]^{\lt\omega}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $X$. Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $[X]^{\lt\omega}$ such that $\{E\in[X]^{\lt\omega}:x\in E\}\in\mathcal U$ for each $x$ in $X$. Let's say that a statement $P(E)$ holds *for almost all* $E\in[X]^{\lt\omega}$ if $\{E\in[X]^{\lt\omega}:P(E)\}\in\mathcal U$. Now define
$$\mathcal F=\{A\subseteq X:|A\cap E|\text{ is even for almost all }E\in[X]^{\lt\omega}\}.$$
Then (a) and (b) are satisfied.

**More generally:** For any positive integer $n$ and any set $A$, there is a function $f:\mathcal P(A)\to\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ satisfying the conditions:
(1) $f(X)\equiv|X|\pmod n$ for every finite set $X\subseteq A$;
(2) if $X,Y\subseteq A$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then $f(X\cup Y)\equiv f(X)+f(Y)\pmod n$.

Comment: +1: Does this proof work for any property of finite sets?

Comment: Not sure what generalization you have in mind. What exactly do you want to hold for any property of finite sets?

Comment: An example of a property I have in mind (substituting "is even") is "the elements are pairwise comparable (given an established ordering)". I'm trying to connect the ideas I learned from this proof to the well-ordering theorem or more interestingly/plausible Teichmuller-Tukey lemma.

Comment: OK but what do you want to prove about that property, or any property of finite sets?

Comment: I guess to boil down what I'm interested in is this construction of $\mathcal{F}$. (You can ignore my previous comment). It seems if I replace "is even" to "is odd" we get another construction with similar properties. It seems that properties usually only given to finite sets that are "dichotomous" can be extended to infinite sets via this construction. A more concrete question is can I use "is prime" or "is composite" instead of "even/odd."

Comment: If $P(E)$ is the property "$E$ is totally ordered" (by a given ordering), then "almost all finite subsets of $A$ satisfy $P(E)$" is equivalent to "all finite subsets of $A$ satisfy $P(E)$". This is because (1) given a finite set $E_0$, almost all finite sets contain $E_0$ as a subset, and (2) a subset of a totally ordered set is totally ordered" i.e., "totally ordered" is a monotone property, unlike "has even number of elements".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89806/discussion-between-alberto-takase-and-bof).

Comment: To the proposer: Zorn's Lemma is "hidden" in the existence of the ultra-filter.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The proposer seems to be long gone. I don't know much set theory but I believe I read somewhere that the ultrafilter extension theorem is weaker than AC, whereas Zorn's lemma is equivalent. More interesting question is whether this problem has a "constructive" solution, or is some form of choice unavoidable? For instance, does the existence of such $\mathcal F$ imply the existence of a nontrivial ultrafilter?

Comment: @bof your time was much appreciated!

Comment: I dk whether an instance of AC is needed. The Q  does not ask for a maximal family F.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Maximality is automatic: one family satisfying (a) and (b) can't be contained in another.

Comment: You've given me something to ponder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following?

$$\mathcal{F}:=\{A\subseteq X:\#A\in2\mathbb{N}\text{ or ($A$ is infinite and $\#(X\setminus A)\in 2\mathbb{N}$})\}$$

<s>Let me know if you need more details.</s>

Comment: I definitely missed the nuance of this question... I am in progress of finding a better idea

Comment: Not sure I understand your updated answer. If $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are both infinite, I guess that means $A\notin\mathcal F$? But then what if you partition $A$ into two disjoint sets $X$ and $Y$, you will have $X\notin\mathcal F$, $Y\notin\mathcal F$, and $X\cup Y\notin\mathcal F$, right?

Comment: yeah currently it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for that comment. I was about to ponder for too long before considering that possibility!